# How to get src of dynamic loaded images

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics

Accordingly to the documentation document.images should give me a list of images being loaded. However in the following page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.images

if you run on the console the command document.images it will return an empty array [], run document.images.length and it will return 0.

I ran into this by looking on how Adobe is doing it in PDP: https://www.adobetag.com/d1/digitalpulsedebugger/live/DPD.js to get their tracking pixel which I am trying to get as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no images on [the Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.images), that's why it's `0`. The ["images" you saw](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/redesign/img/logo_sprite.svg?2014-01) are loaded in CSS, while `document.images` will only return a list of "images in the current HTML document."

If you try `$("img").length` on that page, you will see that it is 0.

---

Quoting the [original text](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) from the W3C Recommentation:

> A collection of all the `IMG` elements in a document. **The behavior is limited to `IMG` elements** for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I will open a new very similar question which asks how does Adobe capture the image list of dynamic images per the second part of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The page has no images (img tags).

The images you see come from the sprite sheet: https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/redesign/img/logo_sprite.svg

This is set as background image & clipped, as required.